# Secure iframe in unsecure document?

Tags: security, iframe

I'm building a website for a sports center. Registrations are handled through a third-party software program. There are options to register directly through the third party's site or to integrate the registration form into my site with iframes.

Since I'd rather not send people to another site, I went with the iframes option. My question is, can I be sure that people will be getting the same level of security in the iframe as they would on the completely-secure third-party page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design does make you more prone to [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/). I recommended watching the video of Moxie Marlenspike's Talk.  Although in practice such an attack isn't common.

This iframe would not be a violation of [OWASP A9: Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management).  However if you are planning on letting people login to the HTTP site, or if you are transmitting a session id over HTTP  then this would be **clear violation** of OWASP A9.

In short, https is absolutely necessary to protect your users.

Comment: Thanks, Rook. The only transmission of personal info will be done within the iframe. I'm just not familiar enough with security to handle it.

Comment: @Beau no problem man.  Its good that you can recognize your own faults.

Comment: If you're thinking about allowing "secure" content to be `iframe`d at all, you should at least consider clickjacking attacks before doing that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking -- in most cases allowing iframing is a bad idea but in some cases it's okay.

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen yes but clickjacking a registration form isn't very helpful.  It is more of a concern for configuration pages and like buttons.

Comment: @Rook: that's correct. Just make sure that *all* other forms are protected from clickjacking. I believe that one often made error is to allow framing of all forms instead of just one form.